# Java Swing do-while Null Pointer [persisting] Confusion

Tags: java, arrays, swing, nullpointerexception, do-while

I am continuing to receive this NPE despite the following evidence I have that my array does in fact exist:
Using this code I reference a 2D array of strings, I select an element at random, the first of the two sub-elements:

```
do{
        hold = (oneRay.length);
        pick = random.nextInt(hold);
        System.out.println("called(); has been called - oneRay.length = 
" + oneRay.length + "oneRay[0].length " + oneRay[pick].length);
    }while("".equals(oneRay[pick][0]));
    area.setText(oneRay[pick][0]);
```

From the console, I receive the error that an NPE occurred - how can this be, when my Random object is initialized, and because of my println checkpoints I can clearly see that the array is full and therefore exists:

```
called(); has been called - oneRay.length = 15oneRay[0].length2
called(); has been called - oneRay.length = 15oneRay[0].length2
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at wbh.SwingImplementation.called(SwingImplementation.java:105)
```

I have been having this problem since yesterday despite my attempts to work around it - my arrays are clearly copying, so what then is this NullPointer?
Thanks to all who have and, hopefully, will help me!
Cheers

Comment: An array of references can exist, but contain null references. Null references can be copied, but cannot be used to access an object.

Comment: When you initialize an array `String[] arr = new String[X]`, it contains X null references as its elements. You have to initialize each element.

Comment: And if you want to debug this, use a `new Random( seed )` with a fixed seed where you can reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

For `oneRay[0].length`, the 0th element of the array must have a value.
For `oneRay[pick].length`, the pickth element of the array must have a value.